# Why do we require that $1 \in A$ in defining n-admissible functions?

Tags: recursion, peano-axioms

In the proof of the Iteration Theorem in Eliot Mendelson's book [Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis (1973)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/XiPYwAEACAAJ), page 57, the author defines a function $f: A \to W$ to be n-admissible iff:

1. $A \subseteq P$
2. $1 \in A$
3. $n \in A$
4. $\forall u (S(u) \in A \implies u \in A)$
5. $f(1) = c$
6. $\forall u (S(u) \in A \implies f(S(u)) = g(f(u))).$

I don't see why we need (2). Do (3) and (4) not imply that $1 \in A$?

Comment: Is it Mendelson's [Mathematical Logic](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic/FS-sCQAAQBAJ)? If so, what page?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It's from Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis, page 58.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'm a little bit perplexed... In another book by the same author ([Mathematical Logic](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic/FS-sCQAAQBAJ), page 385), the assumptions of the Theorem amounts to: $f(0)=c$ and $\forall x (x \in A \to f(s(x))=g(f(x)))$.

Comment: Having said that, I agree with you: we start with $A \subseteq P$, i.e. $A$ is a set of "numbers" and the def of $n$-admissible requires that $n \in A$. But condition (4) ensures that all *previous* numbers will be in $A$, up to $1$ (that is not a successor).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes! Thank you.